# Windows phone app, how to use narrator read page title automatically?

Tags: windows, accessibility, uwp, narrator

I'm developing windows universal app(XAML,C#) on phone, and am enabling accessibility for Narrator. Does anybody know how to get narrator automatically to read page title when a page is opened?

I tried setting automationproperties.name in page but didn't work:

```
<Page
x:Class="xxxxxx"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
AutomationProperties.Name="Page title to be read"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The features of the Narrator for UWP are applied when you select a control in a list, or editing a textbox. If you want to read content when the app is opened you should use the SpeechSynthesizer API, which is really easy to implement:

1.- In XAML add a Media Element

```
    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement"/>
```

2.-Then in the code behind of the page:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadTitle();
    }

    private async void ReadTitle()
    {
        var voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First();
        SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer() { Voice = voice };
        var text= this.GetValue(AutomationProperties.NameProperty) as String; 
        await reader.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

        MediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        MediaElement.Play();
    }
```

You can read everything you want passing the string to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make view-able by narrator. I don't believe you can declare the Name property within the Page Class. Try something like this within the content of your Page:

```
<HyperlinkButton
    NavigateUri="www.bing.com"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationID="bing url" //Not Required to work
    AutomationProperties.Name="Go to the Bing Homepage"//Narrator will read this
    <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="Bing Dot Com" />
       <TextBlock Text="www.bing.com" />
    <StackPanel>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.peers.accessibilityview

**EDIT:** You may also need to programmatically set focus on the item for this to work